# Enable ping to pass through pfSense

Tags: ping, pfsense, wide-area-network

I have a pfSense v1.2.3 running and want to allow ping from the WAN through to my LAN and allow the response to get through. Web traffic goes through just fine, but not pings. As suggested elsewhere I have a firewall rule like the following:

Action: Pass

Interface: WAN

ICMP Type: Echo

Source: any

Destination: Wan Address

But the pings are still not happening. Networking is not my specialty. Can anyone point me to where I might be going wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to ping and what are you trying to achieve? That rule makes no sense to me - surely the destination should be whatever you're attempting to ping?

Comment: I'd like to ping a server on the LAN side of the pfSense from any IP on the WAN side of the pfSense. The server answers pings from the LAN side to the LAN side, I'm just having trouble passing that stuff through the pfSense to the internet (WAN).

Comment: If you've got NAT going this isn't really possibly. If you don't have NAT you can just add a rule to allow ICMP from any to any.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dan - by setting the destination as the WAN address you are being selective and only allowing pings to your WAN address with this rule. Change the destination to ANY  and it should work as requested.

However by doing this an outsider could potentially deduce what ip addresses you have in use internally, my preference would be to only allow this from trusted addresses.

Off topic - 2.0.1 is out now which adds a lot more functionality.